# Jira-Python - jira.client import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, jira

I was installing jira-python like written in the docs

$ pip install jira-python

but after installation I try to run the example:

```
from jira.client import JIRA
options = {
    'server': 'https://jira.atlassian.com'
}
jira = JIRA(options)

projects = jira.projects()

keys = sorted([project.key for project in projects])[2:5]

issue = jira.issue('JRA-1330')

import re
atl_comments = [comment for comment in issue.fields.comment.comments
                if re.search(r'@atlassian.com$', comment.author.emailAddress)]

jira.add_comment(issue, 'Comment text')

issue.update(summary="I'm different!", description='Changed the summary to be different.')

issue.delete()
```

getting the following error:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jira.py", line 4, in <module>
    from jira.client import JIRA
  File "/home/ubuntu/jira.py", line 4, in <module>
    from jira.client import JIRA
ImportError: No module named client**
```

Any idea about the problem here? I tried it also on an Amazon instance, but same problem...

Comment: first of all, make sure you dont have different versions of python and that you did not install to the wrong place, second of all, you need to make sure it installed correctly, thirdly, it might be a problem with the pathing, you might need to add to the system pypath or someting.

Comment: The python version is Python 2.7.2, so that should be no problem and the paths are all default :(. But I'll try your tip with the pypath.

Comment: in case it was not clear, the problem is that python can not find your module, i remember i think i had a similar issue with jira once, and the pathing solved it. but you might also be good with simply retrying to install it using a different method, or simply copying the files over to your python lib.

Comment: ouch, seems like the reason was that my test file was named jira.py :) thanks for your help Inbar!

Comment: answer your own question and accept the answer. it might help others in the future, and its not good to leave open questions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

seems like the reason was that my test file was named jira.py :) thanks for your help Inbar!

Comment: Holy Crap! I made the same mistake today.

Comment: I also did the same thing.

Comment: Its 2016 and I made the same mistake! In case someone else is getting the error even after renaming the file, remember to remove jira.pyc (compiled) file.

Comment: same here, haha :)

Comment: this is the answer!